Newton-Kantorovich theorem: geometric intuition
I am trying to find some geometric intuition for the Newton-Kantorovich theorem, and I have investigated the special case of real numbers. The theorem states:

$$\textbf{The Newton-Kantorovich theorem}$$
Given a differentiable function $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open interval, let $x_0$ be a point in  $\Omega$ such that its derivative at that point is invertible ($f'(x_0)^{-1}$ is defined).
Define
$$h_0=-f(x_0)^{-1}f(x_0)$$$$x_1=x_0+h_0$$
If the open ball $B(x_1, \|h_0\|)$ is contained inside $\Omega$, and $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of the derivative $f'(x)$ over the ball (in other words, for all $x,y \in B(x_1,\|h_0\|)$, $$\frac{\|f'(x)-f'(y)\|}{\|x-y\|} \leq L$$), then if the inequality
$$\|f(x_0)\|\|f'(x_0)^{-1}\|^2L \leq \frac{1}{2}$$
is satisfied, then:

$f(x)=0$ has a unique solution in the closed ball $\bar B(x_1,\|h_0|)$
the Newton iteration starting from $x_0$ converges to this solution at least linearly.


Let's take the special case of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and take the graph of its derivative $f'(x)$. I refer to the term $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ as a "Newton step" of $f$ from $x$.
Claude 3.5 Sonnet has given me the idea of constructing a triangle since there is a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$, which appears in the formula for the area of a triangle. So I played around with this idea and the connection between the derivative and the slope.
Firstly, I verified the geometric intuition behind the Newton step: starting from $(x,f(x))$, we can draw a tangent line on the graph until the x-intercept, forming a right-angled triangle.

If we calculate the magnitude of the Newton step $\Delta x$ using the slope formula $|f'(x)|=\frac{|f(x)|}{|\Delta x|}$, we get $$|\Delta x| = \frac{|f(x)|}{|f'(x)|}$$as expected.
Seeing how the ratio between a function and its derivative can be interpreted this way, this prompted me to use the same reasoning on the graph of the derivative function. Using the same logic, taking a Newton step on the derivative function gives
$$|\Delta x|=\frac{|f'(x)|}{|f''(x)|}$$
But now, if we look at the triangle similar to the previous diagram formed by this Newton step on $f'(x)$, we can now calculate its area as
$$\text{Area}=\frac{1}{2}|\Delta x||f'(x)|=\frac{1}{2}\frac{|f'(x)|^2}{|f''(x)|}$$
This is strikingly reminiscent of the inequality in the Newton-Kantorovich theorem, just with $f''(x)$ instead of the Lipschitz constant for $f'(x)$. This forms a kind of meta-Newton step (more specifically, gradient descent with Lipschitz step size) where, instead of having
$$x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{f'(x)}{f''(x)}$$
we use
$$x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{f'(x)}{L}$$
where $L$ is a Lipschitz constant on $f'(x)$. Based on the Mean Value theorem, we could use a bound on the second derivative as a Lipschitz constant for $f'(x)$. I don't know if there's some meaningful connection there.
Now, we can re-arrange the terms in the theorem's inequality in the following way:
$$|f(x_0)| \leq \frac{1}{2}\frac{|f'(x_0)|^2}{L}$$
In natural language, we would then describe the Newton-Kantorovich theorem (omitting all the description of $f(x)$) for real-valued functions as:

If the operator norm of the output value of the function at the initial guessing point is less than or equal to the area of the triangle formed by the gradient descent step with Lipschitz step size, and the open ball centered at that point with its radius being the norm of the Newton step at that point is contained inside the domain of the function, then the Newton iteration will converge at least linearly to the unique solution contained inside the closed version of that ball.

Algebraically, if we extend this into $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can get
$$\|f(x_0)\| \leq \frac{1}{2}\frac{\|f'(x_0)^{-1}\|^{-2}}{L} \leq \frac{1}{2}\frac{\|f'(x_0)\|^2}{L}$$
since $f'(x_0)$ is bounded and linear so
$$\|x\|=\|f'(x_0)^{-1}f'(x_0)(x)\| \leq \|f'(x_0)^{-1}\|\|f'(x_0)\|\|x\|$$
$$\|f'(x_0)^{-1}\|^{-1} \leq \|f'(x_0)\|$$
Unfortunately, this would mean that the bound with the derivative's norm instead of the reciprocal of the derivative inverse's norm is in fact looser and would not fulfil the criteria.
For the sake of illustration, let's take the concrete example
$$x \in \, ]0,2[$$
$$f(x):=\frac{x^{4}}{4}-\frac{x^{2}}{2}$$
$$f'(x)=x^3-x$$
$$f''(x)=3x^2-1$$
The Desmos project can be found here.

This function has a root at $x=\sqrt(2) \approx 1.414$. Now, let's take $x_0=1.5$ as our starting point, where  $f(1.5) = 0.140625$ and $f'(1.5)=1.875$.

Taking our first Newton step, we have that $\|h_0\| = \frac{0.140625}{1.875} = 0.075$, $x_1=1.5-0.075=1.425$.
The open ball $B(1.425,0.075)=]1.35,1.5[$ is indeed in $]0,2[$.
Taking a look at at the graphs, the supremum of the second derivative on the interval $]1.35,1.5[$ is $5.75$. We'll use that as our Lipschitz constant bound for $f'(x)$.

If we then draw the triangle formed by the gradient descent step, its area is
$$\text{Area} \approx \frac{1}{2}|1.5-1.174||1.875| \approx 0.305625$$
This indeed corresponds to
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{f'(1.5)^2}{L}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1.875^2}{5.75} \approx 0.305706522$$

Indeed, $f(x) \leq A$ since $0.141 \leq 0.305$ so the Newton-Kantorovich theorem tells us that the interval $]1.35,1.5[$ has a unique root and the Newton method converges with initial guess $x_0=1.5$.
Questions
Of course, this construction for interpretation is somewhat arbitrary, as comparing units of length to units of area is awkward. Therefore,

Are there more natural geometrical interpretations of this theorem for the case of real numbers, comparing equivalent units? I tried things like ratios, e.g. $$\frac{|f(x)|}{|f'(x)|} \leq \frac{1}{2}\frac{|f'(x)|}{|L|}$$ but it always felt awkward to interpret.
Is there a natural or interesting extension of this interpretation to higher dimensions? Earlier, I've shown algebraically that based on the properties of the operator norm, $$\|f(x_0\| \leq \frac{1}{2}\frac{\|f'(x_0)^{-1}\|^{-2}}{L} \leq \frac{1}{2}\frac{\|f'(x_0)\|^2}{L}$$since $f'(x_0)$ is bounded and linear so $$\|x\|=\|f'(x_0)^{-1}f'(x_0)(x)\| \leq \|f'(x_0)^{-1}\|\|f'(x_0)\|\|x\|$$$$\|f'(x_0)^{-1}\|^{-1} \leq \|f'(x_0)\|$$ but I am not sure what to make of this.
If we are able to find an interesting geometrical perspective, could it be used for a proof of the theorem, or at least a heuristical argument that the iteration will converge?

Thanks in advance.

What do you mean by "Claude 3.5 Sonnet" ?

@JeanMarie It is the latest large language model developed by Anthropic, I find that it is very helpful to come up with ideas.
https://www.anthropic.com/news/claude-3-5-sonnet

Have you tried reading the exposition in Hubbard's Calculus textbook ?  It's helpful.
